# Laravel 5.8 and React Native using pusher: error listening to private channel: No callbacks on conversations34 for pusher:subscription_succeeded

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-native, pusher

The problem is when the app developer tries to listen to the event via pusher private channel. Here's the laravel code.

routes/api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/broadcast/auth', 'Api\Auth\BroadcastAuthController@auth');
```

routs/channels.php:

```
// notifications channel
Broadcast::channel('users.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
  return (int)$user->id === (int)$id;
});
// conversations channel
Broadcast::channel('conversations.{conversation}', function ($user, \App\Models\Conversation 
$conversation) {
    return $conversation->users->contains($user);
```

});

MessageSent event

```
class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
public $message;
/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($message)
{
    $this->message = $message;
}
/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('conversations.' . $this->message->conversation_id);
}
/**
 * Load user relation.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function broadcastWith()
{
    return [
        'message' => $this->message->load('user')
    ];
  }
}
```

React receiving the message

```
var Echotest= new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
  forceTLS: true,
  cluster:"eu",
  authEndpoint: 'https://example.com/api/broadcast/auth' ,
  auth: {
      headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token ,
      }
    }
});
console.log(Echotest);
Echotest.channel("conversations" + this.state.conversation_id)
  .listen("App\Events\MessageSent", e => {
   alert(e)
   });
```

But the result is:

```
Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"channel":"conversations34"}}
Pusher : Event recd : 
{"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","channel":"conversations34","data":{}}
 Pusher : No callbacks on conversations34 for pusher:subscription_succeeded
```

Is there anything else need to be done in Laravel to make it work in react? or the issue in react and need to be fixed? Please advise and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you encounter any other issues receiving messages on the conversations34 channel? The error indicates that the event 'pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded' was received but here is no binding for that event. This shouldn't prevent issues when receiving other events that you have bound to (MessageSent events).

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the "Echotest.channel" to "Echotest.private"